# How to import table to local file system?

Tags: java, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I am trying to export results from a table in hive and using this command:

```
bline --hiveconf hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict --outputformat=csv2 -e "select * from db.table;">~/table.csv

(bline is an alias for beeline -u address + some options)
```

The query finishes but then gives me

```
error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Am I exporting the table correctly or is there a better way to export a table in Hive?

Comment: How is the table stored (TEXTFILE/SEQUENCEFILE/ORC etc.)?

Comment: | ROW FORMAT SERDE                                                    |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'              |
| STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                                               |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'                        |
| OUTPUTFORMAT                                                        |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'      |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your table is stored in text format, you can simply use **get / getmerge** to copy the files from the HDFS to your local file system

- [get](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#get)
- [getmerge](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getmerge)

---

#### Demo

**hive**

```
create table mytable (i int,s string,d date);

insert into mytable values 
    (1,'hello','2017-03-01')
   ,(2,'world','2017-03-02')
;

select * from mytable
;

mytable.i   mytable.s   mytable.d
1   hello   2017-03-01
2   world   2017-03-02

show create table mytable;

CREATE TABLE `mytable`(
  `i` int, 
  `s` string, 
  `d` date)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/mytable'
.
.
.
```

**bash**

```
hdfs dfs -getmerge /user/hive/warehouse/mytable mytable.txt

cat mytable.txt 

1hello2017-03-01
2world2017-03-02
```

P.s.
There is an unseen delimiter between the columns, the character SOH, with ascii value 1.

```
<mytable.txt tr $'\x01' ','
1,hello,2017-03-01
2,world,2017-03-02
```

Comment: How do use this to just make it a CSV file? <mytable.txt awk -F$'\x01' 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{print $1,$2,$3}'

Comment: See bottom of updated answer for simpler option (tr)

Answer (score 0):

Since You wanted a different delimiter, there is a cleaner solution

```
insert overwrite local directory '/tmp/mytable' 
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
select * from mytable
;
```

[LanguageManual DML](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries)

---

#### Demo

**hive**

```
create table mytable (i int,s string,d date);

insert into mytable values 
    (1,'hello','2017-03-01')
   ,(2,'world','2017-03-02')
;

select * from mytable
;

mytable.i   mytable.s   mytable.d
1   hello   2017-03-01
2   world   2017-03-02
```

---

```
insert overwrite local directory '/tmp/mytable' 
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
select * from mytable
;
```

---

**bash**

```
cat /tmp/mytable/*
1,hello,2017-03-01
2,world,2017-03-02
```